# Is there any cost involved in Algolia when i add new Indices replica for my sorting requirements?

Tags: algolia

I have about 5 attributes to be sorted in Algolia and to make them sortable i found i need to add Algolia Replica Indices.

I doubt, that will duplicate data 5 times and hence will suddenly increase my bill to 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the records in the replica indices will count for the billing, like any other index.

Unfortunately there is no workaround to prevent additional cost if you need to have sorting replicas.

Comment: I have decided to replace algolia with ElasticSearch. Yeah there is cost to manage the service but it is way cost effective. Thanks for your response.